# System.Threading.Timer windows service memory leak

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, timer, windbg

I have a c# console application running as a windows service. The main thread of the application uses a `System.Threading.Timer` to manage 'sweeps' of a database. When the sweep starts on timer tick, the timer creates an object to find work in the database, and that object raises an event when work is found to spawn off the job into another thread.

I appear to be suffering a memory leak, and my limited `windbg` abilities querying memory dumps has me thinking that the timer is not releasing something/itself to GC.

`windbg:`

```
!dumpheap -type System.Object[]
...
02b01ae0 73a20cbc    32656   
02b09a80 73a20cbc     4112     
02b0e8e0 73a20cbc    16336     
02b5bf88 73a20cbc     1040     
02b5c3a8 73a20cbc     2064
10ee1010 73a20cbc 268435472     

Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
04210964        1           32 System.Func`2[[System.Type, mscorlib],[System.Func`2[[System.Object[], mscorlib],[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter, Newtonsoft.Json]], mscorlib]]
7366a6a4        1           48 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.Object[], mscorlib]]
04210a5c        1           48 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Type, mscorlib],[System.Func`2[[System.Object[], mscorlib],[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter, Newtonsoft.Json]], mscorlib]]
73a20cbc     1194    268556916 System.Object[]
Total 1198 objects
0:000> !gcroot 10ee1010 
Thread 2dfc:
    04f1f70c 72db0687 System.Net.TimerThread.ThreadProc()
        ebp+50: 04f1f710 (interior)
            ->  02ac33a8 System.Object[]
            ->  072a5a38 System.Net.ServerCertValidationCallback
            ->  072a5a18 System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback
            ->  10ee1010 System.Object[]
```

Simplified and condensed code:

```
TimeSpan timerInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
static Timer t;
public void startTimer()
{
    t = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerTick, null, TimeSpan.Zero, timerInterval);
}
public void TimerTick(Object TimerState)
{
    //run each query sweep synchronously
    t.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
    List<Query> queries = GetQueries();
    foreach (var query in queries)
    {
        var search = new QueryProcessor(query);
        //short term publisher?
        search.resultFoundEvent += QueryResultEventListener;
        search.RunSearch();
    }
    t.Change(timerInterval, timerInterval);
}
public void RunJob(JobDetails job)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => job.Execute(JobCallback));
}
//long term subscriber
public void QueryResultEventListener(object sender, FakeEventArgs e)
{
    RunJob(e.jobdetails);
}
public void JobCallback(JobDetails jobsuccess)
{
    //job was completed
}
```

As commented above, i don't think this is a traditional event handler leak, and `windbg` above has only this one massive entry at the bottom of `!dumpheap -stat` for `System.Object[]`.

Comment: Did you do a `GC.collect`, and `WaitForPendingFinalizers` before the dump?

Comment: @TheGeneral this `windbg` is based on a memory dump from taskmanager of the application running on a client machine. The code above is a simplified version of what's running in production, but neither calls `GC` explicitly.

Comment: The thing is, its hard to tell if this is just garbage waiting to be cleared or a leak. I have never used windbg before, and its pertinent information before worrying about a leak

Comment: If you can, I think you might be better off using Visual Studio's Memory Profiler for trying to find out what's using the memory. It'll probably tell you in more managed terms what's using the memory and where it's being initialised from. Have a look at [Profile Memory Usage in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage) and [Native Memory Leak Diagnostics with Visual Studio 2015](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2014/12/01/native-memory-leak-diagnostics-visual-studio-2015/) and see if they find out the problem.

Comment: @Ciaran_McCarthy thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately i cannot deploy Visual Studio to the client's production environment.

Comment: DebugDiag DotNetMemoryAnalisys report is a very good point to start your memory investigation.
Why do you suspect a leak? You see constant grow of consumed memory and then OOM?
How many threads are there in the process, what are they doing?

Comment: General rule of investigating managed leaks - is to take a dump, let's say at 500 megs and at 1 gig and then compare the state of the managed heap. You'll be able to determine what objects are responsible fo the grow you see and then you can search for the reason. 
You can compare 2 memory dumps using VisualStudio or using PerfVew.

Comment: You could analyze memory dump in more convenient way using JetBrains dotMemory (may be other memory profilers also can do it, don't know).

Comment: @Ed.ward thanks for the suggestion, this tool is definitely superior in helping me along

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jetBrains dotMemory I was able to determine that the handle open was from a line of code being called from referenced managed code down the stack in the `job.Execute()`. It was setting a delegate globally and causing `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` to pin a handle and never release.

`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { };`

Feels like it behaves in the "short term publisher, long term subscriber" classic memory leak fashion, as the parent object of the constructor calling this line was disposed shortly after.